# HTML column-count issue

Tags: html, css

I'm using column-count in order to enable masonry for my image gallery. It works as expected when i set the column-count to 3.

When its 3:

[image]

The issue arises when i set it equal to 4. It seems to maintain 3 and just set whitespace as the 4th column to the right.

When its 4:

[image]

I'm not sure what the issue could be.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#photos {
  line-height: 0;
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
  column-count: 4;
  column-gap: 0;
}

#photos img {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="photos">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't achieve your wish with the   **column-count** bacause you need to know that it works like this **numbers are the standing of the images in HTML** so you may need to add more the have an img in the fourth column

[image]

I suggest to use the flex

```
#photos {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#photos img {
    width: 25%;
}
```

Hope it helped